# Sequelize PostgreSQL: query to see if string is within an array

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

Given that I have a model called `Model` with a column called `items` which holds an array of strings, how can I query to see whether a string `queryString` is in the array or has a similar element in the array?

***Example:***

`items: ["cat", "dog", "bird", "turtle", "doe" ]`

`queryString = ["%do%","%b"]`

**Should return**:

`animalArray = ["dog", "doe", "bird"]`

---

**Edit:** Is there anyway to pair up an $overlap with $iLike somehow?

```
Model.findAll({
    where: {
        items: { $in: { $iLike: { $any: queryString } } }
    }
}).then(function(array){
    // Do whatever here with array
})
```

`$iLike` is a special Postgres thing in [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/)

Thanks!

Comment: wrong data structure. Refer the postgresql arrays documentation (it says if you are searching your arrays you got the wrong strcuture)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

**Step 1:** Create a new array which stored your like conditions

```
var conditions = [];

var queryString = ["%do%","%b"];
```

**Step 2:** loop your queryString values

```
for(var x in queryString) {
    // do something
}
```

**Step 3:** inside loop just append your `$like` condition

```
conditions.push({
    items: {
        $like: queryString[x]
    }
});
```

So your array would be like this

```
[{
    items: {
        $like: "%do%"
    }
},{
    items: {
        $like: "%b"
    }
}]
```

So your sequelize query would be like this

```
var conditions = [];
var queryString = ["%do%","%b"];

for(var x in queryString) {
    conditions.push({
        items: {
            $like: queryString[x]
        }
    });
}

Model.findAll({
    where: {or: conditions}
}).then(function(array){
    // Do whatever here with array
})
```

Comment: I've tried this already. You can't compare an array with a string iirc. Thanks for the attempt though!